# ThreadPoolExecutor mysteriously rejecting runnables

Tags: java, threadpool

Given the following unit tests, can somebody explain to me as to why at some point the ThreadPoolExecutor rejects a tasks?

```
 @Test
public void testRejectionBehavior() throws Exception {
    final AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);
    final AtomicInteger activeThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
    for (;;) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20,
                                               0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                               new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        int prestarted = pool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
        pool.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
        System.out.println("Prestarted #" + prestarted);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            final int thisTasksActive = activeThreads.incrementAndGet();
            pool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long value = count.incrementAndGet();
                    if (value % 50 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Execution #" + value + " / active: "  + thisTasksActive);
                    }
                    if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("main")) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Execution #" + value + " / active: "  + thisTasksActive);
                    }
                    activeThreads.decrementAndGet();
                }
            });
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    }
}
```

The output for me looks like this:

```
....
Execution #200 / active: 1
Prestarted #20

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Execution #201 / active: 1 / pool stats: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@156643d4[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 20, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

As you can see, it does some 200 executions and then suddenly rejects the first task of a new iteration.

Comment: And where's the full stacktrace?

Comment: The full stacktrace doesn't add any value to the question. It does in particular not show which reject() trace was used inside the ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of digging into the `ThreadPoolExecutor` it turns out that using the given parameters when creating the `ThreadPoolExecutor` it is not immediately able to execute tasks.

There is actually a race condition even if you invoke `pool.prestartAllCoreThreads();`. You see, `prestartAllCoreThreads()` creates new `ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker` instances which implement `Runnable` interface. When instantiating them they set their internal state to to -1 making them appear as "active threads" in the `toString()` output of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Now also in their constructor, the Worker instances create a new Thread and set themselves as `Runnable` for this Thread. It is not until their `run()` method is actually called by the newly started thread that they set their state to be available for taking on tasks and subsequently calling the `workQueue.take()` method.

In short, when you have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a synchronous queue and prestart all Threads, it might take a while for these threads to really start up and block in the `queue.take()` state. It is not until then that you can submit tasks and not get a rejected execution.

Comment: please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) -- and never try to manipulate internal executor task algorithms like that

Comment: You should add some code snippets to this answer, so others don't have to go dig as deep as you did.

Comment: I would add code examples but things get really messy real quick when you look into the ThreadPoolExecutor source code. For example, the state of the ThreadPool (Running, Shutdown,...) and the amount of workers is coded into a single AtomicInteger, just to save a little space....

Answer (score -2):

You haven't provided a proper queue for the executor to store the tasks in. A `SynchronousQueue` has no capacity, not even 1. You fill out the threadpool and then your next task has to run on the main thread as is the normal behaviour in this case.

`SynchronousQueue` is a weird beast, and the only time I've seen it being used in code on SO is with executors. In questions like "why does my code act weird". How did you come up with using a `SynchronousQueue` here?

Comment: Your answer while generally right doesn't really go into the details why this is happening under the given circumstances. I understand that my tasks will be rejected if all workers of the ThreadPool are busy executing a task - which is exactly what I want. However, in the given example, it clearly indicates that only one worker should be busy (active: 1) and thus all other 19 workers should be in the state of blocking while trying to take the next task from the SynchronousQueue...

Comment: please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) -- and never try to manipulate internal executor task algorithms like that

Comment: @specializt What's that supposed to mean? He's not using a single thread executor and he's not manipulating any internal algorithms.

Comment: he **is** using a *"a single thread executor"* and he **is** manipulating internal algorithms by using `SynchronousQueue` - this blocks internal initialization algorithms, of course - it would've probably caused a lot of more problems, also

Comment: @specializt I have no idea why you think he's using a singlethreadexecutor, when he's clearly not. I also don't understand what your link is supposed to describe. If you have a link that says "don't use `SynchronousQueue` with executors, show it. Otherwise you're not making any sense yet.

Comment: you're kind of confused today, arent you? You're stating that yourself - in your own answer yet you're asking for that very same statement. Also : i think you should re-read what i wrote, probably several times -- until you finally discover that *"a single thread executor"* is something completely different from `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Comment: @specializt Re-read what you wrote where? So far you haven't written anything worth reading, let alone re-reading. You've given a link to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` javadoc saying "read this", and saying "don't manipulate internal algorithms". Is your link supposed to point somewhere else? If I'm confused, it's only because you're confusing.

Comment: @specializt: Actually using a SynchronousQueue is suggested by the JavaDoc of ThreadPoolExecutor (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), see the section about Queuing and especially direct handoffs. Also I'm not using a single thread executor, very specifically I have 20 threads (see my example again).